# GROUP BY of the result of the inner query is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO of the result of inner query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT O.CUSTADDRESSID, O.ACCOUNTNO, D.ORGANISATIONNAME
      FROM db.sc.TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES O FULL OUTER JOIN
           db.sc.TP_CUSTOMER_BUSINESS D 
      ON O.ACCOUNTNO = D.ACCOUNTNO
     ) a 
GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO 
ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO;
```

But I am getting this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
>       Column 'a.CUSTADDRESSID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Need help. Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove  " GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO "  - query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT
   O.CUSTADDRESSID, O.ACCOUNTNO,
   D.ORGANISATIONNAME
FROM
   db.sc.TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES O    FULL OUTER JOIN db.sc.TP_CUSTOMER_BUSINESS D ON O.ACCOUNTNO = D.ACCOUNTNO) a 
ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO
```

or list all columns in group by - query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT
       O.CUSTADDRESSID, O.ACCOUNTNO,
       D.ORGANISATIONNAME
    FROM
       db.sc.TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES O    FULL OUTER JOIN db.sc.TP_CUSTOMER_BUSINESS D ON O.ACCOUNTNO = D.ACCOUNTNO) a 
    GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO, CUSTADDRESSID, ORGANISATIONNAME
    ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO
```

Answer (score 1):

The group by and select are not same, here is a sample:

```
SELECT ACCOUNTNO, CUSTADDRESSID, ORGANISATIONNAME FROM (
  SELECT
   O.CUSTADDRESSID, O.ACCOUNTNO,
   D.ORGANISATIONNAME
   FROM
   db.sc.TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES O    FULL OUTER JOIN db.sc.TP_CUSTOMER_BUSINESS D ON O.ACCOUNTNO = D.ACCOUNTNO
   ) a 
 GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO, CUSTADDRESSID, ORGANISATIONNAME  ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO
```